# What are the throttling limits for using the Microsoft BotFramework SDK?

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I have created a chatbot using the CSharp Bot runtime & the Directline Webchat, that runs the botframework sdk. I am currently not using any of the Azure services except the Directline API.

I wanted to know about the throttling limits of the usage of the SDK. Is there any documentation available for it.

Answer (score 0):

Per the BF documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-faq-general?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#what-are-the-rate-limits):

> We're continuously tuning the rate limits to make them as lenient as possible while at the same time protecting our service and our users. Because thresholds will occasionally change, we aren't publishing the numbers at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But as per the documentation it looks like they have provided a general statement. Is there any documentation of what the hard limits are ?